# How to return all occurrences that match in a list?

Tags: python

I have the following Code. I have a file with a bunch of data in it and i want to return all occurrences of whatever data i enter into the prompt. However the code i have just returns the first occurrence. i want to know how to return all occurrences. This only returns the first one it finds in the list. How would i change this to return all occurrences. For example if i want it to return all occurrences of PG13 movies that match that rating instead of the first how would i do this?

```
def getRating(titlesList,ratingList,ratingname):
    #This function will take the ratings,films and userrating parameters
    #It will look through the ratings list to search for the specific rating 
    #the user chooses
    #It then returns a list of all the films of a certain rating
    i = 0
    found = 0
    while i < len(ratingList) and found == 0:
        if ratingname == ratingList[i]:
            found = 1
        else:
            i = i + 1
    if found == 1:
        return i
    else:
        return ""
```

Comment: The current code you have either returns a number (the index of the first matching rating), or an empty string if no match was found. Is that really what you intend? You're not using the `titlesList` argument at all, so I'm wondering if `return i` is supposed to be `return titlesList[i]`. Is there a reason that you're using a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop?

Comment: i just wanted to return the indexes that way i can use the indexes in my other function to match every index in the other list to return the same values. i have a couple list i need to match.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Have you done any debugging? As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: _However the code i have just returns the first occurrence. i want to know how to return all occurrences._ What is the point of returning just the occurrences? What information does that provide which cannot be obtained in another (better) way? _For example if i want it to return all occurrences of PG13 movies that match that rating instead of the first how would i do this?_ **There's no way for us to help with that based on the information we have.** The current code doesn't do anything involving the titles.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getRating(titlesList,ratingList,ratingname):
    #This function will take the ratings,films and userrating parameters
    #It will look through the ratings list to search for the specific rating 
    #the user chooses
    #It then returns a list of all the films of a certain rating
    i = 0
    found = 0
    listOfFilms = []
    while i < len(ratingList):
        if ratingname == ratingList[i]:
            found = 1
            listOfFilms.append(ratingList[i])
        else:
            i += 1
    if found == 1:
        return listOfFilms
    else:
        return "There's no occurrences"
```

Your mistake is that you return the flag i, which can be useless in referring to anything. Instead, create an empty list and append each matching occurrence.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Unfortunately this code makes little sense, mostly because the original code doesn't.

Comment: There's a lot of parameters involved. So I didn't change much. You asked why it returns only the first element. So to solve that, the usually solution would be to declare an empty list, and use the function 'append' to add to it; and that's what I did.